# Retrieve GMAIL messsages for multiple mailboxes (subjects) in one API call?

Tags: gmail

I've nailed down getting all the messages for a SINGLE subject (`user1@mydomain.com`)

```
let client = new google.auth.JWT({
  email: "SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL", 
  key: "SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY",
  scopes: SCOPES,
  subject: 'user1@mydomain.com' <-- Looking to get 100+ subjects
});

const msgs = await google.gmail('v1').users.messages.list({
  auth: client,
  userId: 'me',
  maxResults: 1,
  q:"is:unread"
});
```

What I'm looking for is to get messages for MULTIPLE subjects at the same time `user1@mydomain.com`, `user2@mydomain.com`, `user3@mydomain.com` around 100+ of these.
I COULD loop through all of these using `forEach` and make get api call, but i feel thats very inefficient for 100+ of these. I was hoping to get insights into a better way to do this. Any suggestions on how I could go about this?

Answer (score 0):

That's because the service account only has access to the single service associated with the subject

If you want to access data for a different user than just change subject and create a new service this way it will be accessing that user instead so basically in your case you're going to need three different ones you can't create a single authorization access that has access to data for three different users it's a single user that it has access to

Comment: I'm using an AWS Lambda function. Does that mean in Lambda invocation per subject? ie I pass along the the subject as an event and initialize the jwt client with that subject on the fly or something along those lines?